# Print kable table to .tex file

Tags: r, latex, kable

I have a table generated in kable that I want to print to a .tex file, in the same way I would use print.xtable.

that is,

`print(xtable(data.frame, xtable.options), print.options, file = filename.tex))`

When I tacked print onto a kable table generation, it doesn't work.  It seems to be ignored.

I am using:

`kable(df, format = 'latex', kable.options) %>% print(file = filename.tex)`

Note, the pipe operator `%>%` should drop the preceding into the first argument of the following function.  I do not see a print.kable function available.  Is there some other function I am missing?

I am using kable to allow for grouping columns; something xtable by default doesn't appear to allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cat` -

```
cat(kable(head(mtcars), format = 'latex'), file = 'file.tex')
```

Comment: I ended up using ```capture.output()```, which apparently also worked.